# Large http payloads aren't getting sent to the Serilog Http Sink endpoint in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, serilog

## Summary

I'm having trouble posting from Serilog (Http Sink) to my custom .NET Core 3.1 WebAPI endpoint when the logging data is large. If I remove some log data when I do the logging, then Serilog sinks properly with my WebAPI endpoint.

## My Configuration

```
            new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                     .WriteTo.Http(httpPath, httpClient: new CustomHttpClient(), batchPostingLimit: int.MaxValue, queueLimit: int.MaxValue)
                     .CreateLogger();
```

## My Custom Http Client

```
public class CustomHttpClient : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient c_httpClient;

    public CustomHttpClient()
    {
        c_httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483647L
        };
    }

    public void Configure(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content) => c_httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);

    public void Dispose() => c_httpClient?.Dispose();
}
```

## What actually does the logging

```
            var exceptionModel = new AppMonModel
            {
                Application = "SerilogMvc Sample Application",
                Message = ex.Message,
                Source = "SerilogMvc.HomeController.Index",
                StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
                InnerException = ex.InnerException?.StackTrace,
                Details = "Sample details here",
                InsertDate = DateTime.Now,
                Severity = 100,
                UserDescription = "Keyvan User",
                ScreenshotBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:/SamplePath/Untitled.png"))
            };
            
            c_logger.LogError(ex, "{exceptionModel}", exceptionModel);
```

## My Endpoint

```
    [HttpPost("log")]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public void Log([FromBody] object logEvents) { ... }
```

## Serilog Error

Event JSON representation exceeds the byte size limit of 262144 set for this sink and will be dropped;

## Issue

When I remove `ScreenshotBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:/SamplePath/Untitled.png"))` from my exceptionModel object, I see the error in my WebAPI endpoint. As soon as I add it back in, it doesn't even hit the endpoint.

Please let me know if you need additional details. I'd be more than glad to provide them.

Comment: I would like to help you, but I need you to create a GitHub repository with the code showcasing the issue. You don't have to start from scratch if you don't want, I think you can copy a lot of code from https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-core

Comment: @FantasticFiasco Thank you very much for looking at this: https://github.com/ksadralodabai/serilogshowcase. It's a "skeleton" application that also has me disabling request limits, form limits, etc.

Comment: @FantasticFiasco also if it helps, this is the Serilog self log message, "Event JSON representation exceeds the byte size limit of 262144 set for this sink and will be dropped;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simple after turning on Self logging. This is the change I needed to make to increase the batch formatter size:

```
        var defaultBatchFormatter = new DefaultBatchFormatter(batchFormatterSize);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .MinimumLevel.Error()
                     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                     .WriteTo.Http(httpPath, batchFormatter: defaultBatchFormatter)
                     .CreateLogger();
```

The batch formatter size needed to be increased.

Comment: I've added this issue to my wiki: https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/wiki/Common-problems#large-sized-log-events-arent-received-by-the-log-server-while-ordinary-sized-log-events-are. Thank you for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 2):

Need to add eventBodyLimitBytes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ail8b.png)

```
   .WriteTo.Seq(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqServerUrl) ? "http://seq" : seqServerUrl, eventBodyLimitBytes: 1048576)
```